# Spark coalesce vs HDFS getmerge

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, coalesce

I am developing a program in Spark. I need to have the results in a single file, so there are two ways to merge the result:

- Coalesce (Spark):

> myRDD.coalesce(1, false).saveAsTextFile(pathOut);

- Merge it afterwards in HDFS:

> hadoop fs -getmerge pathOut localPath

Which one is most efficient and quick?

Is there any other method to merge the files in HDFS (like "getmerge") saving the result to HDFS, instead of getting it to a local path?

Comment: I’m strongly recommending you, do not use ```FileUtil.copyMerge``` or ```hadoop fs -getmerge``` because it copies data to driver (look at source code).

Comment: Coalesce is very memory heavy, it might cause a GC overhead as well. I would just merge the file using cat* in bash script which can be triggered in a separate json call.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure your data fits in memory probably coalesce is the best option but in other case in order to avoid an OOM error I would use getMerge or if you are using Scala/Java [copyMerge](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileUtil.html#copyMerge(org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem,%20org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path,%20boolean,%20org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.String)) API function from FileUtil class.

Check this [thread](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201509.mbox/%3CCAAKWyE-ZbaVadhGs-0yzpnjX7P42k2_FRwGWy-4KkOot3+pdKA@mail.gmail.com%3E) of spark user mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're processing a large dataset (and I assume you are), I would recommend letting Spark write each partition to its own "part" file in HDFS and then using `hadoop fs -getMerge` to extract a single output file from the HDFS directory.

Spark splits the data up into partitions for efficiency, so it can distribute the workload among many worker nodes. If you coalesce to a small number of partitions, you reduce its ability to distribute the work, and with just 1 partition you're putting all the work on a single node. At best this will be slower, at worst it will run out of memory and crash the job.